# Using the verb "prefer" for specific and general preferences (with/without time frame)

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

In the following scenario,  both of the sentences in each pair mean exactly the same to me. If they don't, please let me know why?

> **A)** Good restaurant. 
>   **B)** Yea, but they don't offer a good variety of drinks along with food. They only have two options.
>   Well; which one is your choice? Orange juice or apple juice? 
>   **A)** ....

**1.1.** I prefer orange juice. 
**1.2.** I'd prefer orange juice.

**2.1.** I **always** prefer orange juice. 
**2.2.** I'd **always** prefer orange juice.

**3.1.** I prefer orange juice **now**. 
**3.2.** I'd prefer orange juice **now**.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional in all the examples indicates personal liking and more involves personal attitute towards it, if you have more than one option, it says that you better go for this option and not the other one, that this one you like more.
The statements without conditional implicate kind of general statement, like generally speaking.

E.x. 1. I prefer orange juice (always when you hang out with your friend you order it because it’s your favorite one)
2.I’d prefer orange juice (indicates a situation in which you are  at restaurant right now right and waiter is asking you which one would you like to order from the list of drinks)